# add url to list of webpages in csv using python

Tags: python, csv

I Have a csv file containing the following data:
PageName, ID
Index, 1
Images, 2
Sounds, 3
Applications, 4
Games, 5
...

I want to add a prefixed url, to each of the pages listed under "PageName"
(Example, making "Index", to be "https://www.example.com/Index").

**Update:**
I've tried to use the following code to do so:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('small.csv', 'rb'))
writer = csv.writer(open('full.csv', 'wb'))
for row in reader:
    writer.writerow("https://www.example.com/" + [row[0], row[1]])
```

But i get the error:
writer.writerow("https://www.example.com/" + [row[0], row[1]])
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

**Update 2:**
My bad.
haven't formatted the code properly (according to @Linuxios's answer).
now everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
writer.writerow(["https://www.example.com/" + row[0], row[1]])
```

To prevent this from *also* prepending the URL to the header, add this before the loop to pass the headers through unchanged:

```
writer.writerow(reader.next())
```

Comment: I tried it, but now i get a different error:
writer.writerow("https://www.example.com/" + [row[0], row[1]]) TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Comment: @TomKidron: Again, you are misplacing the `[`. Place it *before* `"example.com"`.